# Terminology help - similar to strongly connected

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for a directed graph in which for every vertex $v$ there exists a path between $v$ and every other vertex $u$? The paths can be either v->u or u->v as long as a "connection" exists.

Comment: Just "[connected](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory))"

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page here: Lets say we have a graph G with V={a, b, c} and E={{a, b}, {c, b}}. This would not be "connected" right? Although there are edges between all vertices, there is no way to get from a to c or vice versa.

Comment: Right. However it would be *weakly* connected (since the underlying undirected graph is connected).